# Why are points where $\alpha'(t) = 0$ called singular points?

Tags: differential-geometry

Apparently for a parametrized differentiable curve $\alpha: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, for each $t \in I$ such that $\alpha'(t) \neq 0$ there is a well defined straight line - the tangent line. But why is this not true for $\alpha'(t) = 0.$ Wouldn't it just be a horizontal line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you're confusing the *graph* of a function and a parametrized curve. In the case you have here, the direction vector of the tangent line is the derivative vector; if it is $0$, you have no direction vector.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

To add to the previous answer, visually, it is not hard to tell the singular points in this image. In rough terms, they correspond to the points at which it is not clear "where to go next". The tangent vector "carries" you along the curve. This is well defined for nonsingular points. But at a singular point,  the tangent vector vanishes  ($\alpha'(t)=0$) and you must stop so there is no natural way to continue traveling along the curve.

(The image is from Wolfram Alpha and hopefully constitutes fair use)

Comment: Not all of these are relevant, though--for instance, a node (ordinary double point) is not a singular point in the sense of $\alpha'(t)=0$.

Comment: Thank you for the visual aid.